# Adding an item to a many to many association using Ecto

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a 'boards' module that has an association to 'users'.

I want to simply add a user to the 'users' assocation.

```
 schema "boards" do
    # ...

    many_to_many :users, User, join_through: "boards_users"

    timestamps()
  end
```

Now in my code I have just inserted a new record and I have a 'board' instance.

I want to associate a 'user' to this board, but currently I have to do the following.

Is there an easier way to do this?  Seems like allot of code to simply append/associate a user to the 'users' collection on the 'board' module.

1. I have to reload the 'board' instance to preload all the users
2. I append the user
3. I have to call change, then put_assoc and then call update

*Is this what I have to do or am I doing it in a very verbose way?*

**I want to avoid having to load all the users** when I am just appending another user to the collection, is this possible?

```
board = Repo.get(__MODULE__, id) |> Repo.preload(:users)

board_users = board.users ++ [user] 
                  |> Enum.map(&Ecto.Changeset.change/1)

board
|> Ecto.Changeset.change
|> Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc(:users, board_users)
|> Repo.update
```

Answer (score 2):

It's really easy if you will not **skip** your *join* table, but cover it with one more schema:

```rb
schema "boards_users" do
  belongs_to :user, User
  belongs_to :board, Board
end
```

Then, the request will look like:

```rb
%BoardUser{user: u, board: b}
|> Repo.insert()
```

With this approach, you can even get alone with **single** request to the database

```rb
%BoardUser{user_id: user_id, board_id: id)
|> Repo.insert()
```

Here, you should not hit the database to get the board, while all validations can be performed by DB via right defined foreign keys.